# Invariant subfields and Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\alpha\in K$ be a root of $f$. Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ that fixes $\alpha$. Let $N=N_G(H)=\{g\in G| g(\alpha)\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\}$.

> Is it true that the number of distinct subfields of $K$ which is ismorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ equal $|G|/|N|$ (so this number doesn't depend on $n=deg(f)$ explicitly)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe so. 
If $L$ is a subfield of $K$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, then since $K$ is a splitting field this isomorphism can be extended to an automorphism $K \to K$ fixing $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e an element $\sigma$ of $G=Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$. So $L=\sigma(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))$, i.e every subfield of $L$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is a Galois conjugate of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

So $G$ acts on the set of subfields of $K$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ (because this set is the same as the set of conjugates of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$), and the stabilizer for this action is $N=\{g \in G \mid g(\alpha) \in \mathbb{Q}(a)\}$. So the size of the orbit is the order of the group divided by the size of the stabilizer.